# Is saving custom object to user default and then getting back is kind of memento stuffs?

Tags: ios, swift

[Swift & iOS]

i was reading about memento pattern, i felt there is some similarity between memento pattern and when we save and get back custom object in/from UserDefault.

Is that the memento kind of stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a memento kind of saving user state and reload it when the app opens again , but with custom objects you need not use userdefaults it's meant when saving settings but instead use coredata/releam

Comment: yeah, but what if only small amount of data, which doesn't require much security. let say only 1 object.

Comment: it's up to you but you can consider keychain wrapper instead https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift

Comment: hmm, keychain i use for normally those data which requires security. like user related data.